# I get a 403 when requesting a JS file from CloudFront

Tags: amazon-s3, cname-record, amazon-cloudfront

This is new to me so please excuse me if I have no idea what I'm talking about (: I'm trying to set up my own CDN with CloudFront and S3 through a subdomain by adding a CNAME to that subdomain to point to the CloudFront.

It seems like I get a 403 when trying to load the file, this is the original s3 [link](https://s3.amazonaws.com/chaoscod3r_aws_cdn/libs/polyfills/json3_polyfill.js) which seems to be working after setting the permission to everyone to open / download. But when trying to use the subdomain to request the file : http://cdn.chaoscod3r.com/libs/polyfills/json3_polyfill.js ; it seems like I get that 403.

Could anyone help me out with this one ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've to add the CNAME to the CloudFront distribution's settings as well.
Simply goto 
`AWS Console > CloudFront > Distribution > Distribution Settings > Alternate Domain Names(CNAMEs)` and add the CNAME value cdn.chaoscod3r.com over there.

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html

Comment: what if I have the CNAME added? 

I'm getting 403 Error:

ERROR

The request could not be satisfied.

Bad request.

Comment: Make sure in your route53 settings, your A / CNAME records are set up with: Alias Target: `dxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net`  <-- *with no period at the end!!!!*

Comment: is following helpful? https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/resolve-cloudfront-bad-request-error/